# Bind JSlider knob to an external int value

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jslider

My `JSlider` has a `iconScaleManager` as an attribute. The `iconScaleManager` possesses a `int` which value corresponds to the `JSlider` ticks. That `int` is modified by another class, an `ActionListener`, which is added on 2 JButtons.

The goal is : I would like the knob to move, on its own, to the actual value of the `int` which corresponds to the tick mark.
I guess I need to bind the value or to fire an event, but I couldn't figure how to.

And of course, I added aChangeListener on the JSlider :

```
public class SliderListener implements ChangeListener {
     private int sliderIndex = 0;
     private IconScaleManager iconScaleManager = null;

     public SliderListener(int startingIndex, IconScaleManager renderer) {
         sliderIndex = startingIndex;
         iconScaleManager = renderer;
     }

     @Override
     public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
         JSlider source = (JSlider)e.getSource();
         sliderIndex = source.getValue();
         iconScaleManager.scaleSlider(sliderIndex);
     }  
}
```

Comment: Either your button `ActionListener`s need to change the state of the `JSlider`, or probably more preferably, the `IconScaleManager` manager needs to generate some kind of "state changed" event, to which your UI can register to and update the `JSlider` accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simpler use, I made the button's `ActionListener` change the state of the `JSlider` (`setValue(iconScaleManager.getScaleIndex())`) in `actionPerformed()`. (It was simpler than I thought). Thanks to @MadProgrammer.

```
public class ZoomListener implements ActionListener {
    private boolean zoomIn = false;
    private JSlider zoomSlider = null;
    private IconScaleManager iconScaleManager = null;

    public ZoomListener(boolean zoom, JSlider slider, IconScaleManager renderer) {
        zoomIn = zoom;
        zoomSlider = slider;
        iconScaleManager = renderer;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        iconScaleManager.scaleButton(zoomIn);
        System.out.println(iconScaleManager.getScaleIndex());
        zoomSlider.setValue(iconScaleManager.getScaleIndex());
    }
}
```